# Twilio StatusCallback not working when modifying a live call

Tags: php, api, rest, twilio

I am trying to forward a call in Twilio by modifying the live call. I have a number set up that will get the zip code from the caller and then determine the customer number to forward that call to by searching in a database. For the first part of the call (to get the zip code) I'm using the Gather verb. Once I have the zip code and customer's assigned Twilio number I can forward the call using the REST API to modify the live call.

I need to add some extra parameters to the callback URL with a GET request.

According to Twilio's website I should be able to POST the StatusCallbackURL and Method to the modified call.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state

However, it is not working. Here is my code:

```
$url = 'http://xxxx.com/phone/customer?to='.$number;

$call = $this->twilio->account->calls->get($this->request->query->get('CallSid'));
$call->update(array(
  'Url' => $url,
  'Method' => 'GET',
  'StatusCallbackMethod' => 'GET',
  'StatusCallback' => 'http://xxxx.com/phone/log/callback'
));
```

The "Url" and "Method" optional parameters work but Twilio does not call back to the supplied callback URL.

The new URL that twilio redirects the call to returns TwiML for twilio to process.

The call is initiated by an actual person picking up the phone and calling. I tried to create a call via the REST API and the StatusCallback works but twilio expects TwiML to be returned so I get an error in twilio.